# My checkbox is not binding with the member

Tags: xaml, silverlight

Say we have a grid view which is binding with the data source MyInformation. One of column is a check box. I want to bind something with it.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding MyInformation}"
```

In the ViewModel.

```
public ObservableCollection<Container> MyInformation
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.myInformation == null)
            {
                this.myInformation = new ObservableCollection<Container>();
            }
            return this.myInformation;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.myInformation != value)
            {
                this.myInformation = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("MyInformation");
            }
        }
    }
```

The class Container has a member "GoodValue".

```
public class Container
{
    public bool GoodValue {get;set;}
    //
}
```

I have the checkbox bind with the member.

```
<DataTemplate>
  <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding GoodValue, Converter={StaticResource ShortToBooleanConverter}}" Click="CheckBox_Checked"></CheckBox>
  </DataTemplate>
```

I don't have the property `GoodValue` created in ViewModel as I think `GoodValue`  is a member of Container. The ObservableCollection includes it automatically.

The problem is each time I read the data from the database. The checkbox is unchecked. So I doubt my code. Thanks for hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1. Check if there are some **binding errors**
2. Implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface into your class Container.

   public class Container:INotifyPropertyChanged
       {

   ```
      private bool _goodValue;

       public string GoodValue
       {
           get
           {
               return _goodValue;
           }
           set
           {
               _goodValue = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("GoodValue");
           }
       }

       protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
       {
           PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   }
   ```

The **ObservableCollection** is usefull if you want to notify to your view when a new item is inserted or deleted from the collection, but if the object contained inside it doesn't implement InotifyPropertyChanged, the changes to properties of that object won't affect any change to your view.

Comment: Just find the error. My ShortToBooleanConverter is wrong. When true it is 1, false is 0. But in my case, the value in the table is not 1/0. I have to rewrite the converter.